# TeX to html converter

Tags: html, latex

What is the best way to convert latex document with PGF & TikZ images to html files?

Comment: Does `latex2html` not work well with those image types? Or with something you have in your document?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tex4ht is what I used for this.  http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/~gurari/TeX4ht/  But I haven't tried it on documents with PGF so I don't know if it will work for you.  But in general I found that program much much much more useful than latex2html.

Answer (score 2):

use TeXMaker html converter: [TexMaker Portable](http://www.parsilatex.com/download/Texmaker-1.9.9_portable_BiDi%20%5BPi%20Day%202010%5D.zip) and [TeX Maker bidi](http://rghost.net/users/ra3401/releases/texmaker-bidi) (BiDirectional support)

works  clear.

Comment: I installed TexMaker, where is the html converter?

Answer (score -1):

If you really need HTML files, your best bet is to run pdflatex, then process the pdf files to  html using a pdf-to-HTML program. (I recommend trying http://pdftohtml.sourceforge.net/). You may want to convert the images and the text separately.

Comment: What's the point if you have to convert the images and text separately? Besides, a pdf to html method is going to bomb horribly if there's math involved.

Comment: You can still automate separate conversion. Likewise, for math, you can convert the map as bitmaps